# How to move child element inside parent element tracked by mouse position

Tags: javascript

I want to make an eye which watches to mouse cursor. The pupil of eye should't  leaving the "eye" border
[image][image] [image] 
I've created some sandbox, which shows example of HTML markup, but I don 't have a formula to make this animation works https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-butterfly-grwkz

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/build-an-eye-tracking-alien-with-javascript-solution-to-code-challenge-4)

i have to type any thing to post this
The base of our challenge consisted of HTML and CSS which constructed the Alien body.
Divs were used to create individual parts of the Alien including the monster, body, ears, mouth, tooth, and eye.

```
<div class="ufo">
  <div class="monster" style="color: #7cb342">
    <div class="body">
      <div class="ear"></div>
      <div class="ear"></div>
      <div class="vampi-mouth">
        <div class="vampi-tooth"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="eye-lid">
      <div class="eyes">
        <div class="eye"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've seen those post before and the main difference is: 1) Eyes maked as circles, not as ellipse, so it means that this formula will not work; 2) If you put mouse right over to pupil it not "sees" to cursor